# Animation in Jquery, Step by step execution

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am using following code to animate in Jquery. I want step2 to occur when step1 is completly executed. At the moment both steps run at same time hence i get background-image as image2.jpg, while image1.jpg is set at css style. HELP PLEASE? I am new to jquery

step:1

```
$("#atn").animate({top:"+=335"},3000).animate({top:"-50px"},1000).animate({top:"0"},2000).animate({width:"hide"},0);
```

step:2

```
$("#atn").css("background-image", "url(images/image2.jpg)");
```

*NOTE: Step two might be different `div` eg. `#atn2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the callback of `animate`.

```
$("#atn").animate({top:"+=335"},3000).animate({top:"-50px"},1000).animate({top:"0"},2000)
         .animate({width:"hide"},0, function(){
             $("#atn2").css("background-image", "url(images/image2.jpg)");
         });
```